# Data type mismatch in criteria expression + manipulação de dados Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-excel

Analise para ver se a lógica está coerente, por favor.
O procedimento desse código é:

Consultar uma `procedure` e armazenar os dados dela em uma `DataTable`:

```
 private DataTable ExportPerformanceEntrega()
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder strSql = new StringBuilder();
            strSql.Append("sp_ExportPerformanceEntrega");
            SqlParameter[] parametros = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@empIni", txtEmpIni.Text),
                                                             new SqlParameter("@empFim", txtEmpFim.Text),
                                                             new SqlParameter("@dtIni", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDtIni.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                                                             new SqlParameter("@dtFim", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDtFim.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                                                             (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlAreaBaixa.SelectedValue) ? new SqlParameter("@areaBaixa", DBNull.Value): new SqlParameter("@areaBaixa", ddlAreaBaixa.SelectedValue))};
            return SqlDAO.consultarSQLProc(strSql, parametros);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Aqui é o método deveria fazer o `UPDATE` / `INSERT` em uma planilha existente já.

```
 private void AtualizarPerformanceEntrega()
    {
        try
        {

            DataTable dt = ExportPerformanceEntrega();

            string sFileXLSX = @"C:\Entrega\Performance.xlsx";// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportPerformanceEntrega"];
            if (File.Exists(sFileXLSX))
            {
                string strConnXLSX = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + sFileXLSX + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnXLSX))
                    {
                        //SQL para fazer a cosnulta
                        string strSQL;                        
                        OleDbCommand cmd;
                        OleDbDataReader dts;
                        if ((string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "No Prazo" || (string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Fora do Prazo" || (string)row["StatusEntrega"] == "Antes do Prazo")
                        {


                            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [BaseEntregue$] WHERE NFEmpresa = '" + row["NFEmpresa"] + "' AND NFNumero  = '" + row["NFNumero"] + "' AND NFSerie = '" + row["NFSerie"] + "' AND NFCliente = '" + row["NFCliente"] + "' AND NFPedido = '" + row["NFPedido"] +
                                     "'  AND NFCidade = '" + row["NFCidade"] + "' AND NFUF = '" + row["NFUF"] + "' AND Regiao = '" + row["Regiao"] + "' AND NFTransp = '" + row["NFTransp"] + "' AND NomeTransp = '" + row["NomeTransp"] +
                                     "'  AND DataEmbarque = '" + row["DataEmbarque"] + "' AND DataPrevEntrega = '" + row["DataPrevEntrega"] + "' AND DataEntrega = '" + row["DataEntrega"] + "' AND StatusEntrega = '" + row["StatusEntrega"] + "' AND DiasAtraso = '" + row["DiasAtraso"] + "' AND CodOcorrencia = '" + row["CodOCorrencia"] +
                                     "' AND DescrOcorrencia = '" + row["DescrOcorrencia"] + "'";
                           // Criando o OleDbCommand com o SQL e a conexão
                            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                            // Abrindo a conexão
                            connection.Open();
                            //Executando o SELECT
                            dts = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            //FECHANDO CONEXAO
                            connection.Close();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFEmpresa", row["NFEmpresa"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFNumero", row["NFNumero"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFSerie", row["NFSerie"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFCliente", row["NFCliente"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFPedido", row["NFPedido"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFCidade", row["NFCidade"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFUF", row["NFUF"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regiao", row["Regiao"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFTransp", row["NFTransp"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomeTransp", row["NomeTransp"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataEmbarque", row["DataEmbarque"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataPrevEntrega", row["DataPrevEntrega"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataEntrega", row["DataEntrega"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusEntrega", row["StatusEntrega"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiasAtraso", row["DiasAtraso"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodOcorrencia", row["CodOcorrencia"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescrOcorrencia", row["DescrOcorrencia"]);


                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {


                                strSQL = "UPDATE [BaseEntregue$] SET NFEmpresa = @NFEmpresa, NFNumero = @NFNumero, NFSerie = @NFSerie, NFCliente = @NFCliente, NFPedido = @NFPedido, " + 
                                "NFCidade = @NFCidade, NFUF = @NFUF, Regiao = @Regiao, NFTransp = @NFTransp, NomeTransp = @NomeTransp, DataEmbarque = @DataEmbarque, DataPrevEntrega = @DataPrevEntrega, " +
                                "DataEntrega = @DataEntrega, StatusEntrega = @StatusEntrega, DiasAtraso = @DiasAtraso, CodOcorrencia = @CodOcorrencia, DescrOcorrencia = @DescrOcorrencia " +
                                "WHERE NFEmpresa = @NFEmpresa AND NFNumero = @NFNumero AND NFSerie = @NFSerie AND NFCliente = @NFCliente AND NFPedido = @NFPedido";
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFEmpresa", row["NFEmpresa"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFNumero", row["NFNumero"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFSerie", row["NFSerie"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFCliente", row["NFCliente"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFPedido", row["NFPedido"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFCidade", row["NFCidade"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFUF", row["NFUF"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Regiao", row["Regiao"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NFTransp", row["NFTransp"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@NomeTransp", row["NomeTransp"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DataEmbarque", row["DataEmbarque"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DataPrevEntrega", row["DataPrevEntrega"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DataEntrega", row["DataEntrega"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@StatusEntrega", row["StatusEntrega"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DiasAtraso", row["DiasAtraso"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@CodOcorrencia", row["CodOcorrencia"]));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DescrOcorrencia", row["DescrOcorrencia"]));
                                cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                                //Abrindo a conexão
                                connection.Open();
                                //Executando o UPDATE
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                //Fechando a conexão
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                         }
                      }
```

Porém fica me retornando esse erro:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que as coisas estão sendo feitas na ordem errada.

Você está executando o comando antes de especificar os parâmetros com os valores.

```
 dts = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // Executa o comando (query)
 //FECHANDO CONEXAO
 connection.Close();
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFEmpresa", row["NFEmpresa"]); // Adiciona os parâmetros da query depois de ter executado ela, não adianta muita coisa...
```

O correto é especificar os parâmetros **antes** de executar o comando, pois ele precisa deles para executar a comando, não depois.

**Exemplo:**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFEmpresa", row["NFEmpresa"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFNumero", row["NFNumero"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NFSerie", row["NFSerie"]);
// Outros parâmetros...
connection.Open();
dts = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Use o datareader e após usar ele aí você fecha a conexão.
```

Outra coisa é que você está reutilizando o mesmo comando para duas queries.
Pode ser que funcione, mas antes de declarar o parâmetros da segunda query, limpe os parâmetros da primeira.

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
// Agora adicione os parâmetros da segunda query...
```

Isso deve ser ajustado nos seus dois comandos.